# The system hang while calling sqlSesssion.flushStatement()

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, sql-update, executorservice, sql-sessions

I'm using some SQL query with MyBatis to update data to my Oracle db, but the system stop half way and not throwing any error.

Some forum say that it might because of connection pool size, time out problem or might be `SqlSessionFactory` configuration problem.

I changed all the timeout to 30 sec but still have the same problem

```
//my hikari datasource setup
@Bean
public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource db = new HikariDataSource();
    db.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    db.setJdbcUrl(url);
    db.setUsername(username);
    db.setPassword(pwd);
    db.setReadOnly(false);
    db.setMaximunPoolSize(80);
    db.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
    db.setIdleTimeout(30000);
    db.setMaxLifetime(30000);
    db.setMinimunIdle(5);
    db.setValidationTimeout(500);
    return db;
}
```

The section I'm calling update to my Oracle db

```
try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH)) {
  ItemMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(ItemMapper.class);

  for (Object obj: lists) {
    //It only works fine when I'm calling insert function
    mapper.update(obj);
  }

  //After running this statement then system got stuck
  sqlSession.flushStatements();
  sqlSession.clearCache();
  sqlSession.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is MyBatis .xml file

```
<update id="update">
  UPDATE <include refid="tableName" />
  SET
    item_price = #{price},
    update_time = #{updateTime}
  WHERE id = #{id}
</update>
```

But the weird things is everything works fine while I'm calling insert sql statement, the system will hang or stuck at `sqlSession.flushStatements();` and not throwing any errors only when I change to update sql statement.

**UPDATE**
Even I use normal MyBatis update query also make the whole system hang but nothing happen if I use insert query..

The normal update query i execute

```
Obj obj = new Obj();
obj.setprice("1");
obj.setupdateTime(new Date());
mapper.update(obj);
```

Comment: How many updates are performed in one batch ? How long one update is running ? Are many threads update the table simultanously, or is this a single thread update only? Are there any transactions uncommited  in another session ?

Comment: @krokodilko For testing purpose I've try minimize to 10 rows in a batch in only a thread. It should not have other uncommited session as I restart my server every single time.. For my case it stuck there forever and not continue to run following line of code

Comment: Somehow I successfully update once in million times of trying with the same code, only one time==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solve weirdly, seems like there is some uncommited session in somewhere although I actually restarted my server.

Just manually one click of commit button in Oracle database, then my program able to update data in database.

Please feel free to share any relevant information about some weird uncommited session of Oracle database here